# How can I retrieve an external .properties file in Java?

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, inputstream, properties-file

I have the following problem trying to load a properties file from a directory that is external to my project.

So my project have the following structure:

```
PROJECT-ROOT
     |
     |
     |-----> confi
     |
     |------> src
               |
               |
               |------> mainPkg (the package name)
                           |
                           |
                           |------> Main (the main class containing the main() method)
```

Ok so into the main class I need to load the **config.properties** file situated outside the project root folder (for example at the same level). So I think that **config.properties** file is external to the application classpath.

So I tried to do something like this:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("../../config.properties");
```

or

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("../../../config.properties");
```

but don't work because I obtain the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\..\config.properties (Impossibile trovare il file specificato)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at mainPkg.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

If I use an absolute path like this it works:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Projects\\edi-sta\\config.properties");
```

and correctly retrieve the **InputStrea** object. But this is not good for my purpose because I can't use absolute path.

How can I retrieve my **config.properties** file that is situated at the same level of the project root folder using relative path?

Comment: Note: your relative path is relative to the working directory during execution -- not the directory containing your source file. During development, in an IDE, you can set the working directory in your launcher. In production, you can compute an absolute path from the jar file location, using `MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`.

Comment: If the properties file isn't included in the jar itself, then it should either be read from the current working directory or specified with a command-line argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *project root* would be your programs's *current working directory*. So, you should try with

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("../config.properties");
```

This however is not the recommended setup. The file should be placed inside the project directory and should be jar'd appropriately if and when you publish your application.

Answer (score 2):

If the config.properties file is out of classpath you should use a folder as a starting point (for example user folder or current working folder).

Instead if the file is within your classpath you can try with this.class.getResourceAsStream or this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream().

In a simple context the difference between the two invokations is quite simple:
this.class.getResoursceAsStream("config.properties") will return an InputStream if and only if the file is in the same package of class invoking the method.

Instead this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properites") will return the same InputStream only if the file is on the root of classpath. In this case you have to add "config" folder to the classpath